# Using unsqueeze to get a 2-D torch tensor size for labels with a class instance?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torchvision

I am struggling to get the correct shape for my y (labels for a multiclassification problem) which should be of torch.Size([37715, 1]).
I have tried .unsqueeze(0),.unsqueeze(1) and np.reshape yet I am still getting torch.Size([1]) as in the code belo.  with .unsqeeze(-2) I am getting torch.Size([171812]).

```
import numpy as np
import torch
...
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Lambda
..
# defining the class
class EmbeddingDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, embedding_fp, transform=None, target_transform=None):

        with open(embedding_fp, "rb") as fIn:
            stored_data = pickle.load(fIn)
            stored_labels = stored_data['labels']
            stored_embeddings = stored_data['embeddings']
        self.X = stored_embeddings 
        self.X = torch.tensor(self.X).float().unsqueeze(0)
        self.y = stored_labels.to_numpy()
#        self.y = np.reshape(self.y, (len(self.y), -1))  , alternatively

        self.y= torch.tensor(self.y).float().unsqueeze(-1)
        


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        X = self.X[idx]
        y = self.y[idx]

    
        return X, y
        
# creating a class instance for my training data.

train_data = EmbeddingDataset('embeddings_db_train.pkl')

X_train, y_train = train_data[0]

X_train.shape
torch.Size([171812, 384])

y_train.shape
torch.Size([1])
```

Can anyone advise how can I get shape ([37715, 1]) for my y?
also any suggestions how to define my class in a better way would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

trimming this down, essentially you have:

```
y = torch.tensor(y).float().unsqueeze(-1)
y_train.shape
torch.Size([1])
```

wrapping a tensor in tensor is just... maybe a copy? maybe not even that. so really what you have is:

```
y = y.unsqueeze(-1)
y_train.shape
torch.Size([1])
```

This implies that your starting `y` is a scalar, not a tensor. E.g.:

```
torch.tensor(0).unsqueeze(-1).shape
torch.Size([1])
```

You're asking how to turn a single number into an array of 37715 numbers, and then unsqueeze an extra dimension on that list. What do you want to be in this array of 37715 values? just, the single number repeated 37715 times?

You could do that with:

```
torch.tensor(0).expand(37715).unsqueeze(-1).shape
torch.Size([37715, 1])
```

I'm guessing this isn't really what you wanted though. Maybe you thought you were starting with a tensor of 37715 values? you actually only have one value. Maybe you have a single integer value in the range of 0...37715 and are trying to convert that to a one-hot encoded vector? That would explain why you're trying to do `.float()`.

Here's another way to get the shape you want, which I'm kind of guessing is probably really what you wanted. I used num_classes=10 for readability:

```
num_classes=10 # Note that you'd want to use 37715
value = 3
torch.nn.functional.one_hot(torch.tensor(value), num_classes).unsqueeze(-1)

tensor([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [1],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]])
```